# Can't view application servers in Idea

Tags: java, jboss, intellij-idea

I'm trying to configure JBoss server in idea. I added it as application server:

[image: JBoss correctly added]

but I can't open tab application servers:

[image: can't open view]

I have ultimate edition of Idea. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'Application Servers" tool window becomes available once you have defined a run/debug configuration for a server. That tool window then shows all the server run/debug configurations and their statuses.

Go to Run > Edit Configurations to define a configuration. Use the `help` button for assistance. If you have any problems, post back and I (or someone else) can assist you.